# C Programming of Libharu on Debian

Tags: c

I having a lot of problems setting up my programming environment on Debian. I am trying to write a C program to create pdf documents. I have installed libharu by issuing the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libhpdf-dev
```

I can find hpdf.h in /usr/include folder. I am trying to make sure that the program is installed properly by using a sample code (http://libharu.sourceforge.net/demo/text_demo.c) I found on the internet.

I tried compiling the program by issuing the following command:

```
gcc pdf.c and was treated to a long list of errors:
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccR8ovya.o: in function `main':
pdf.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `HPDF_New'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `HPDF_Free'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `HPDF_AddPage'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_GetHeight'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_GetWidth'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Rectangle'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x1e2): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextWidth'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x1f5): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x255): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextOut'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x2b7): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x33f): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_ShowText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x3aa): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_ShowText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x3f1): undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x407): undefined reference to `HPDF_SaveToFile'
/usr/bin/ld: pdf.c:(.text+0x413): undefined reference to `HPDF_Free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that the compiler is having problem finding `hpdf.h`.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags. You compile a C file. C++ is a very different language.

Comment: You did not add any library to your compiler call.

Comment: Add `-l hpdf` to your compilation (linking in fact) command

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the website.

```
gcc -o testpdf -O2 -Wall testpdf.c -lhpdf -lz
```

http://libharu.sourceforge.net/compile_your_program.html